# Why do mostly zip format files get corrupt in download managers?

Tags: download-manager

I have been using all kinds of download managers like IDM, Eagle Get and FDM etc. I discover one common point in all: sometimes zip format files get corrupt.

Why do mostly zip format files get corrupt in download managers?

Comment: I'd suspect your source material or your connection. I don't get enough corrupt downloads to even form a hypothesis on which types are most affected. If I lose one a year that would be a generous guess.

Comment: Are you sure the difference is in which files _get_ corrupted, and not instead in which files are able to _detect_ corruption? Could it be that in reality, _all_ of your downloaded files get corrupted equally often, but e.g. audio/video formats just don't detect this immediately?

Answer (score 2):

Hypotheses:

1. Maybe you don't notice corruption in other files.

   There is CRC for data and some redundancy for metadata in zip. Additionally the format stores and uses offsets to locate file headers, each header having a strict signature. So in practice if there is any corruption (byte(s) replacement, insertion or deletion) then the file will lose its coherency and you will discover the corruption while unzipping.

   Many other formats of lossless compression are similarly sensitive.

   For comparison:

   - A slightly corrupted media file (especially a container designed for streaming) often plays mostly fine. The corruption may manifest itself as a glitch you may ignore or never notice while the file keeps being played.
   - A slightly corrupted raw image of a filesystem often can be transferred to a device (CD/DVD/HDD/SSD/USB) as-is. Depending on the type of the filesystem and the nature of the corruption, the filesystem may even look healthy afterwards (i.e. `fsck` or `CHKDSK` or whatever tool will tell you it's healthy). The corruption may affect data or metadata of file(s) you may or may not use later. For some files it may not be fatal. So you may never know.

     This is the reason files that mustn't allow corruption (while media files may) but are not designed to detect it internally (while zip format is) are often published along with information that allows you to verify the correctness of your local copy (hashes like CRC, MD5, SHA) or even to repair it ([par2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive)). Note for this mechanism to be effective a user should manually get the redundant information and initiate checking/repairing. This act requires some knowledge and effort, it may be neglected.
2. Maybe you download relatively many zip files; along with (1) this enhances the impression that mostly zip files get corrupt.

Why corruption occurs in the first place is a separate topic.